# List in a nested json in mariaDB with json_table

Tags: json, database, mariadb, nosql

I can't get the data from a nested json using json_table
My MariaDB server is 10.6.0

```json
set @json='
{
   "id":"9696e1ac-e173-4905-ac51-c47c0ef8c90b",
   "username":"demo@demo.com",
   "firstName":"DEMO",
   "lastName":"DEMO",
   "email":"demo@demo.com",
   "isEnabled":true,
   "attributes":{
      "ASSOCIATED_COMPANY":"CLCORP001,CLCORP002,CLCORP003,CLCORP004,PECORP001,PECORP002,PECORP003,PECORP004,PECORP005,DECORP001",
      "ROLES":"[\"Super Admin\",\"Admin\",\"Executive\"]",
   },
}';
```

I tried this but it doesn't work

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    SELECT  * FROM json_table(@json, '$.*' COLUMNS(NESTED PATH '$.attributes.ROLES[*]'  COLUMNS (roles varchar(250) PATH '$'))) roles
TEXT PATH '$'))) roles
```

Comment: I removed the mysql tag because MariaDB and MySQL are not the same software product. In particular, both of them implemented their JSON features after MariaDB forked.

Comment: From a purely counting `(` / `)`, the `TEXT PATH '$')))` doesn't match any of the 3 open `(` as they are all closed. `ROLES` value appears to be a quoted string rather than an array.

Answer (score 1):

No matter if MySQL or MariaDB: If your json string is not valid, json_object will always fail.

In both MySQL and MariaDB you can use json_valid() function to check your json:

```
set @json='
{
   "id":"9696e1ac-e173-4905-ac51-c47c0ef8c90b",
   "username":"demo@demo.com",
   "firstName":"DEMO",
   "lastName":"DEMO",
   "email":"demo@demo.com",
   "isEnabled":true,
   "attributes":{
      "ASSOCIATED_COMPANY":"CLCORP001,CLCORP002,CLCORP003,CLCORP004,PECORP001,PECORP002,PECORP003,PECORP004,PECORP005,DECORP001",
      "ROLES":"[\"Super Admin\",\"Admin\",\"Executive\"]",
   },
}';

SELECT JSON_VALID(@json);
+-------------------+
| JSON_VALID(@json) |
+-------------------+
|                 0 |
+-------------------+
```

On success JSON_VALID will return 1.

I didn't check in detail, but looks like the extra quotation marks in attributes.ROLES are not allowed.